# Integrate a jQuery function into another in Tabs UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs, jquery-address

I'm trying to integrate one function into another function and am puzzled.

What I'm trying to do is add a jQuery function that will call a random quote, and I want that function to fire on a tab change in jQuery Tabs UI.

This is the random quote function:

```
$.get('quotes.txt', function(data) {
        var quotes = data.split("\@");
        var idx = Math.floor(quotes.length * Math.random());
        $('.quotes').html(quotes[idx]);
    });
```

And below this is the tabs init (along with another function that collapses divs when a tab is changed):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs({
        fx : { 
            opacity: 'toggle' 
        },
        select : function(event, ui) {
            $(".entry-content").hide();                
        }                  //I assume it goes near here, but no luck
    }); 
});
```

Does the quotes function need to have the variables called first?

And, how would it work to make the quote div also use the fx opacity effect when it changes quotes?

**Edit 4/27/11**

This works and uses the fx effect in the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({

        fx: {
            opacity: 'toggle'
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(".entry-content").hide();

            $('div#quotescontainer').load('quotes.html', function () {
                var $quotes = $(this).find('div.quote');
                var n = $quotes.length;
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
                $quotes.hide().eq(random).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should go inside the curly braces

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs({
        fx : { 
            opacity: 'toggle' 
        },
        select : function(event, ui) {
            $(".entry-content").hide();                
            // <-- code goes here
        }                  //I assume it goes near here, but no luck <-- NO!
    }); 
});
```

Personally, I'd put it in the 'show' event of the tab, but that shouldn't be a problem.

I've setup a fiddle with some test code for you to see how it should be : http://jsfiddle.net/PyN5Y/1/

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert('triggered on select');
        doStuff();    
    },
    show: function(event, ui) {
        alert('triggered on show');
        doStuff();
    }
});

function doStuff() {
    alert('doing stuff');
}
```

Comment: Ah, works great. Learning stuff here. And jsfiddle is a great tool. Only problem now is with a full reload of the page, or the first visit to the page, the quotes div is blank, which I can understand, because no tab has been fired. Now I'm wondering if there is a way to include some static text on first page load in `#quotescontainer`, i.e., "Welcome..." instead of a random quote?

Comment: @songdogtech. Well 'show' actually fires on page load as well. 'Select' only fires when someone clicks it. you could also just put the text in the tab itself so that content is shown by default.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would monitor for a change on the tabs and then kick off your quote function.

```
$("#tabs ul li a").click(function(e) {
  update_quote();
}); 

function update_quote() {
    $.get('quotes.txt', function(data) {
        var quotes = data.split("\@");
        var idx = Math.floor(quotes.length * Math.random());
        $('.quotes').fadeOut();
        $('.quotes').html(quotes[idx]);
        $('.quotes').fadeIn();
    });
}
```

The update_quote function could be cleaned up and made simpler, I kept it very verbose so you could see how to update it.  You can chain your jquery effects also.

Comment: Instead of the click function using JohnP's example above would be better, just include the update_quote() function call in the select of the tabs.